# How to pass JVM options to jshell while starting it

Tags: java, java-9, jvm-arguments, jshell

I want to do the following :

`jshell -v -Duser.country=FR -Duser.language=fr`

So as to get for example a personalized `Locale.getDefault()`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$ jshell -R -Dtest1=one
|  Welcome to JShell -- Version 11.0.1
|  For an introduction type: /help intro

jshell> System.getProperty("test1")
$1 ==> "one"
```

It's documented in the help options

```
$ jshell -h
Usage:   jshell <option>... <load-file>...
where possible options include:
    --class-path <path>   Specify where to find user class files
    --module-path <path>  Specify where to find application modules
    --add-modules <module>(,<module>)*
                          Specify modules to resolve, or all modules on the
                            module path if <module> is ALL-MODULE-PATHs
    --enable-preview      Allow code to depend on preview features of this release
    --startup <file>      One run replacement for the startup definitions
    --no-startup          Do not run the startup definitions
    --feedback <mode>     Specify the initial feedback mode. The mode may be
                            predefined (silent, concise, normal, or verbose) or
                            previously user-defined
    -q                    Quiet feedback.  Same as: --feedback concise
    -s                    Really quiet feedback.  Same as: --feedback silent
    -v                    Verbose feedback.  Same as: --feedback verbose
    -J<flag>              Pass <flag> directly to the runtime system.
                            Use one -J for each runtime flag or flag argument
    -R<flag>              Pass <flag> to the remote runtime system.
                            Use one -R for each remote flag or flag argument
    -C<flag>              Pass <flag> to the compiler.
                            Use one -C for each compiler flag or flag argument
    --version             Print version information and exit
    --show-version        Print version information and continue
    --help, -?, -h        Print this synopsis of standard options and exit
    --help-extra, -X      Print help on non-standard options and exit
```

Answer (score 3):

One possible way to do that could be to use a [startup script](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~rfield/tutorial/JShellTutorial.html#start-up-scripts) e.g. **`setLocale.jsh`** where the content of the script would be :

```
java.util.Locale.setDefault(java.util.Locale.CANADA) // set your locale
```

then further you can use on the `jshell` command line

```
/set start <path to setLocale.jst>
```

and ensure resetting the state to apply the change

```
/reset
```

to verify the change in `Locale`, you can do

```
java.util.Locale.getDefault()   // prints en_CA
```

---

Do note, the above implies only to the present session of `jshell`. A setting can be preserved with `-retain` option, so if you use

```
/set start -retain
```

then the set startup script will be loaded on your next invocation of the `jshell` tool as well.